# Vue dynamic html - won't to parse vue data object

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have sample code written in Vue:

```
  template: `
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr v-html="tableHTMLContent"></tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>`,
   data() {
     this.tableHTMLContent: '',
     this.myTextName: 'aaaa'
   },
  methods: {
   addSampleCode() {
     this.tableHTMLContent = '<p> {{ myTextName }} </p>'
   }
  }
```

The problem is with parsing `{{ myTextName }}` tag. Html is injected correctly, but Vue won't to parse myTextName variable. Vue doesn't display aaaa value.
What I have to do to parse Vue tags like {{ }} and others tags like v-for, v-if and so on.

Comment: Please refer:-https://coursetro.com/posts/code/135/Vue-Templating-Tutorial---Interpolation-and-Directives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render data values together with template code within a method you can use Vue.compile( ... )

See this link:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile

Usage Example:

```
var res = Vue.compile('<div><span>{{ msg }}</span></div>')

new Vue({
  data: {
    msg: 'hello'
  },
  render: res.render,
  staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
})
```